# How to redirect incoming flask requests to multiple end points?

Tags: python, flask, web-development-server

I'm a data scientist who is new to Flask (and web development) in general. I have a deep learning model OCR that I want to deploy as a web app. I have three endpoints http://0.0.0.0:5000/get_ocr_api, http://0.0.0.0:5001/get_ocr and http://0.0.0.0:5002/get_ocr_api running on ports 5000,5001 and 5002 respectively. I have a "base" server hosted on port 4999.
All of my requests would be handled by this port.

Ideally, I would like 4999 to redirect requests (could be more than 1) to 5000,5001 and 5002 in a round robin fashion or depending upon which port is not currently in use. I understand that load balancers like NGINX and haproxy take care of this, but I'd like to know if this can be done in a pythonic way or not.

Thanks,
Madhav

Comment: Personally, I’d stick with the tried and tested load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

As you already mentioned, usually this is done with nginx or haproxy.

Anyhow, there is also a Python package for this:

https://pypi.org/project/proxy.py